# CGAffineTransformMakeRotation linker Error

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cgaffinetransform

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:

`_CGAffineTransformMakeRotation`, referenced from:

```
-[JKParentTableViewCell rotateIconToExpanded] in JKParentTableViewCell.o
-[JKParentTableViewCell rotateIconToCollapsed] in JKParentTableViewCell.o
```

`_CGRectZero`, referenced from:

```
-[JKExpandTableView initialize] in JKExpandTableView.o
-[JKParentTableViewCell initWithReuseIdentifier:] in JKParentTableViewCell.o
-[JKSubTableViewCellCell initWithReuseIdentifier:] in JKSubTableViewCellCell.o
```

> ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem too with `JKExpandTableView` too. You can change all of the `_CGRectZero` functions with `CGRectMake(0,0,0,0)`, it worked for me. Im still searching for another issue, and i commented them like this:

- ```
  (void)rotateIconToExpanded {

  [UIView beginAnimations:@"rotateDisclosure" context:nil];

  [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.2];

  //iconImage.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI * 2.5);

  [UIView commitAnimations];
  }
  ```

It doesnt effect the whole project, just when you press table cell, the icon doesnt rotate.